# Odoo- Chat en vivo

Tags: odoo13

tengo un pequeño problema con el live chat de odoo, ya lo implemente, el chat esta funcionando todo funciona perfecto, de igual forma ya edite el widget, su posicion e icono.
El problema es que cuando abro el chat desde un celular, o simplemente redusco el tamaño del sitio web desde 770 pixeles aprox el chat abarca toda la pantalla y no puedo cerrarlo. cuando le doy click para que cierre el chat no responde, si ajusto el tamaño a mas de 770 pixeles aprox el chat recupera su tamaño.
ya intente agregar funciones desde el html donde lo implemento ya que no tengo acceso al HTML del chat y pues no funciona.

si alguien de la comunidad llego a tener el mismo problema y lo pudo soculionar de verdad se lo agradeceria.

estoy usando Odoo 13.
saludos[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.